# Production Clone for an Oracle Test Database

Tags: database, oracle, clone

Our test database got the same database schema as the production database.
I'd like to have following features:

DQL statements should go to the test database. If there's no result, the statement runs on the production environment and returns the result to the test database.

DML statements should only work on the test database.
If I run update tablename set ... where ...; and the statement finds the result on the production database, the result should return to the test database and insert the updated result into the test database.

I think it's called snapshot cloning and is only available for oracle db 12c.
Since we've got version 11.2.0.4, is it possible to build up these features manually, e.g. with triggers and views?

Comment: why not just refresh development daily with a datapump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *very* qualified "yes" to your question, though doing what you suggest is littered with landmines. I wouldn't recommend it.

OP says "... the same database schema as the production database." Do you mean every user, permission, role, table, constraint, index, view, package, function, etc. is the same? Any change to any of these in TEST may cause a DML statement which succeeds in PROD to fail in TEST. There are a lot of data consistency and integrity questions that need to be addressed. [Same is true even if the "database schema" is just 1 user schema.]

The general concept of a database 'snapshot' is looking at the database as a whole, sort of "freezing" EVERYTHING, and then duplicating that frozen picture somewhere else. There's an assumption that a frozen database doesn't have ANY state change -- which makes a copy consistent.

Comment: permisssions, roles, tables, constraints, views are the same.

Comment: You got a point i didn't think about. If there's an update from PROD on a tuple which is also given on TEST, then we get inconsistency. Also processes could be triggered on PROD while on TEST they wouldn't, because of the data state. So I've got to make a snapshot first. Thank you :)